# asp.net check cookie against database on each page request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I'm storing a cookie that will check against a database to grant access to a site.  All session info will be stored in the database.  How do I make a call to the database on every page request to get session info?  Is there a controller that I can run on every page?

Comment: Are you following MVC architecture?

Comment: Yes. @ShashankChaturvedi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually create an Action filter for your controller. In that filter you override `OnActionExecuting` method and inside that method you can fill in your session values. Here is a [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs), where you can find a sample code for creating Action filters.

Comment: I'm still playing with this but it looks like it will do what I want.  Thanks for your help!